# Can you use the the AVX instructions with an i5 2600K if your motherboard doesn't include a video card?

Tags: gpu, avx

From everything I've read, the i5 2500K processor disables it's integrated graphics if it detects an external GPU.  I've got a motherboard that doesn't have an integrated video port so I have to add a PCI video card.  I can't find any video cards that don't have a dedicated GPU.  Does that mean that in order to use the AVX instructions you have to use a motherboard with onboard video?

Comment: AVX is nothing to do with the GPU - it's a SIMD extension on the CPU itself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use AVX. It doesn't depend on a graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing some different things together:

[AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) is an extension of the x86 instruction set architecture and can be used with supporting software under Windows 7 SP1 to speed up calculation. This has nothing to do with the intgreated GPU in the Sandybridge CPU family.

To answer you other question: If you have a P67 based motherboard you can not use the integrated GPU, so you need a dedicated graphics card. If you want to use the integrated GPU you need a H67 based motherboard or a board with the new Z67 chipset, which will be released in the next days.